# How to add scroll in vertical and horizontal scroll in the table without using any libraries

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add vertical and horizontal scroll in the table body without any libraries

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add scrollbar to table in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350930/add-scrollbar-to-table-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these proprities within the table tag in the HTML like this

`<table mdbTable mdbTableScroll scrollY="true" scrollX="true">`

These are proprities of Angular Bootstrap table scroll, you can then define maxWidth and maxHeight of your table